# Can I pass attributes to an instance of selenium webdriver

Tags: python, class, selenium

I'm trying to create a class that can create wedriver instances and add proxies to them, this is only a dumbed down version of what i've already written, but I'm also trying to make a method that will wait for an element to be visible before clicking it, the attribute is isn't getting passed to the driver object.

Edit: The code as it was, was hard to understand out of context so I added the whole class as I'm working on it. I've also changed the click_elem method to a static method but now it just times out even though the element is visible.

```
class Driver:
    proxies = []

    @staticmethod
    def test_proxy(proxy):
        try:
            urllib.urlopen(
                "https://www.google.com",
                proxies={'http': proxy})
            return True
        except IOError:
            print "Connection error! (Check proxy)"
            return False
        else:
            return False

    def get_proxied_driver(self):
        for proxy in self.proxies:
            try:
                myproxy = self.proxies.pop()
                if self.test_proxy(myproxy):
                     proxy = Proxy({
                                'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
                                'httpProxy': myproxy,
                                'ftpProxy': myproxy,
                                'sslProxy': myproxy,
                                'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
                                  })
                    driver     = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)###### chrome, phantom js & IE etc ##
                    is_working = raw_input('Is your proxy working? [y/n]: ') # use selenium assert
                    if is_working == 'y' or is_working == 'Y':
                        return driver
                    if is_working == 'n' or is_working == 'N':
                        driver.quit()
                        continue
                    if not is_working == 'y' or is_working == 'Y' or is_working == 'n' or is_working == 'N':
                        print 'Invallid'
            except:
                continue

    # needs working_proxies.txt in the same dir
    def get_proxies(self):
        with open('working_proxies.txt', 'rb') as working_proxies:
            for proxy in working_proxies:
                proxy.rstrip()
                self.proxies.append(proxy.decode('ascii'))

    def get_proxies_n_driver(self): # same as get_driver but it adds proxies from -
        self.get_proxies()          # working_proxies.txt to proxies list
        driver = self.get_proxied_driver()
        return driver

    @staticmethod
    def click_elem(driver, elem_type, elem):
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((elem_type, elem)))

        if elem_type == By.CLASS_NAME:
            find = find_element_by_class_name
        elem = driver.find(elem).click()

driver = Driver()
#driver.test_proxy('213.136.79.124:80')
new_driver = driver.get_proxies_n_driver()
new_driver.get("https://twitter.com/signup")
driver.click_elem(new_driver, By.CLASS_NAME, "submit_button")
```

I've also got another Script that tests the proxies and then adds them to working_proxies.txt

Comment: I really can't tell what this is supposed to be doing, or why, or how it's being tested / evaulated. Could you try to explain your motivation better and/or post a standalone bit of code? The above doesn't look complete.

Comment: @AndrewRegan Hi, this is the cut down version. I'm trying to make a method that will a html element type/ webdriver method as a argument and the element as the other. The method will wait until the element is visible and the click click it if it's shown within 10 secs. "get_proxied_driver()" gets the firefox driver instance and adds a proxy. I need that instance to have access to the click_elem() method. I've also tried click_elem() as a static method but that didn't work either. I'm sorry if i'm doing something very wrong I'm still learning nd self taught.

Comment: What confused me was the 'Is your proxy working?' user input... also how do you know it's not working? Testing a proxy in code isn't really a newbie thing: you'd want quite a few dedicated true/false tests, and not to combine it with clicking on buttons. So all in all, the concept is fine, having those helper funcs etc, but it's just hard to square with the code I can see here.

Comment: @AndrewRegan I've edited my post as I'm currently working on it. It's just the click_elem method that I'm having trouble with. I just get a timeout error now. I'd prefer to have it as a normal method I just posted as I'm working on it now to add a bit more context.